# Can we retag questions with [partialview] to [asp.net-mvc-partialview]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

At the moment [partialview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/partialview) has <strike>144</strike> <strike>104</strike> 0 questions and no wiki or excerpt. Most of them are referencing the technology used in ASP.NET MVC which has his own tag [asp.net-mvc-partialview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-partialview) which has 204 questions and a correct wiki and excerpt.

Can we retag question with [partialview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/partialview) to [asp.net-mvc-partialview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-partialview) and clean-up/close questions if needed?

I'll do the next 50 within a couple of days...

Comment: I would upvote but I can't because you have 1337 rep :P

Comment: and what is the story of 1337?

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed `1337`, if you read it in Leetspeek, reads LEET, or ELITE

Comment: Upvoted. Sorry to spoil the party. (I did take [a screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6rQgF.png), though.)

Comment: Very much appreciated. That screenshot is now my desktop wallpaper...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just finished the last 50+ questions or so. [partialview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/partialview) will be gone at 03:00 UTC and hopefully not return quickly.